# Having troubles generating Android gradle signed and zipaligned apk

Tags: android, build.gradle, intellij-13

I am having trouble getting a signed zipaligned gradle file built in my Android app. I am using intellij 13.1.4. The error I am receiving is Error:(34, 0) Could not find property 'configstd' on BuildTypeDsl_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, jniDebugBuild=false, renderscriptDebugBuild=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, packageNameSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=null, runProguard=false, zipAlign=true, signingConfig=null}.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
`    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
         }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
         buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
        signingConfigs {
            configstd {
                keyAlias 'myalias'
                keyPassword 'mykeypassword'
                storeFile file('mykeyfile.jks')
                storePassword 'mystorepassword'
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                zipAlign true
                signingConfig configstd
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
                zipAlign false
                signingConfig configstd
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovered to be the problem. I originally had used the intellij's Project Structure->Facets->Android-Gradle to enter the parameters for the build.gradle file. Apparently, when it created the code to insert into the file it left off "signingConfigs" from the name of the object configstd. So in other words the line should read as follows:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.configstd
```